# Google Tag manager not registering Transactions for enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am running a single page checkout and the pagevies are showing fine. however the purchase transactions doesn't seem to be being processed in Google analytics.

- I have the data layer up
- and it seems to be registering the purchase event,
- I have tag enabled with a page view on gtm.dom which has the enhanced ecommerce tag ticked,

but still nothing .

Here is the output from the Datalayer if any one can help would be really appreciative :

```
[  
   {  
      "ecommerce":{  
         "purchase":{  
            "actionField":{  
               "id":"145000010",
               "revenue":295,
               "tax":"0.0000",
               "shipping":"5.0000",
               "coupon":""
            },
            "products":[{  
               "id":"ace002",
               "name":"perfume10Lt",
               "price":"295.0000",
               "quantity":"1.0000"
            }]
         },
         "currencyCode":"USD"
      },
      "event":"purchase"
   },
   {  
      "gtm.start":1438797700099,
      "event":"gtm.js"
   },
   {  
      "ecommerce":{  
         "impressions":0,
         "promoView":0
      }
   },
   {  
      "event":"gtm.dom"
   },
   {  
      "event":"gtm.load"
   }
]
```

Added as requested by comments: The tag seems be being called at GTM.dom so i know its definitely running.

Here is the tracking tag:

[image: tracking tag]

Here is the image from the trigger
[image: Triggr]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of how your ecommerce tag is configured, including the trigger? You should be firing your ecommerce enabled tag when event is "purchase".

Comment: To check the simple things first, did you enable "enhanced e-commerce" in your views ?

Comment: Yep- its working now though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your trigger to fire the tag on the 'purchase' event instead. It may be failing because the ecommerce data layer hasn't been pushed yet before the gtm.Dom event happens.

Comment: Thanks! it was strange because it was working previously. Anyway its work ing well with that tweak.