# Google Tag manager is not recordingTransactions for enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: magento, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I already searched a lot and saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841242/google-tag-manager-not-registering-transactions-for-enhanced-ecommerce).
I setup my google analytics with configuring magento native Google API by using account type the Google tag manager. I am able to see page views, All sessions and sessions with product views. however, the rest are 0. please take a look at the following image:

[image]

I debugged the google tag manager with debug tool and I can see that purchase tracking with purchase event is being fired, however, I do not see it in google analytics.

I already setup what the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841242/google-tag-manager-not-registering-transactions-for-enhanced-ecommerce) provided, 
[image]

Also I see that data layer has the purchase information id,revenue,tax,etc.
[image]
I am wondering what needs to be done so that sessions with transactions will get recorded?

here is the configuration that I have for the tag:
[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what's wrong?

Comment: What I can saw it was done good, but calls my attention the numbers (ie:167.9600 ?). In the past, i have issues because that (when this is not properly set and throw an error) . Try to share the information of the Js console to see any Javascript error in that page and try to debug using the GA debugger plugin for Chrome, This information is really useful to know what is happening. I believe that you purchase hit is never send to the servers..https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: Hi @KemenPaulosPlaza thank you so much for the advise, I will try and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the exact tags that you are using, then there looks to be a typo in your `Purchase` trigger. You've got `Event equals puchase` (typo for "purchase"). You don't need to define this value again, and it would be sufficient to just have `Event name` of `purchase` (ie. you don't need the `This trigger fires on`).

Comment: thank you so much, I will try your solution and update.

Comment: Man you are awesome, don't you know what you did. Thank you